# Espresso can't find a View inside a custom view class

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a custom `View` class `public class Foo extends RelativeLayout{...}` which have an `EditText` in it. The `Foo` class have a XML layout inflated and its `EditText` also have an id but its not able to find the `EditText`

I'm using this Espresso code:

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.edittext), withParent(withId(R.id.name_container)))).check(matches(isDisplayed())).perform(click());
```

And the error message I get is:

> android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in
>   hierarchy found matching: (with id: dk.aura.app.staging:id/edittext
>   and has parent matching: with id:
>   dk.aura.app.staging:id/name_container)

Answer (score 23):

With persistence I found an answer to my own question.

It seems that when accessing View inside another View(nested views), you have to check for if it it `isDescendantOfA()` instead of `withParent()`

So this is the correct way: `onView(allOf(withId(R.id.edittext), isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.name_container)))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));`